PostgreSQL which approach is more resource efficient?
I have Rust Backend and using the Sqlx library I want to insert a single row into a table and then retrieve the latest 10 rows.
Option 1 is to do it all in one query like this:
let new_unit = sqlx::query_as::<_, BaseUnit>(
    "WITH inserted_row AS (
            INSERT INTO product_unit (name)
            VALUES ($1)
            RETURNING id, name
        )
        SELECT * FROM (
            select * from product_unit
            union all
            select * from inserted_row
        ) as combined
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 10;",
)

Option 2 is to use two separate queries one executed after the other.
Now which would be considered more resource-efficient?

Run from the client, the two statement approach is probably slower (network latency, per-statement overhead).
If you put both statements into a PL/pgSQL function that might be faster (plan caching). – Laurenz Albe
